# Unable to change Xamarin.Forms.Button Mouseover for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms

I'm developping an APP using Xamarin.Forms using only WPF and Cocoa (macOS) entry points.

The Xamrin.Forms.Button as a default mouseover that seems impossible to override.
Their is no DataTrigger for IsMouseOver on Xamarin.Forms.Button control (only on the WPF one).
If I use a custom Renderer to set the style from the WPF project, I manage to get rid of the default over style using OverideDefaultStyle setter property.But then I need to redefine the whole Button style from WPF project whih is not ideal. I'd like to have most of my style defined in the shared project and if possible only making plateform specific code for handling the mouseover event that doesn't exists on Android and IOS.

I also tried effects without success. I can easily fire code when my mouse over the button but no way to prevent the default blueish color defined somewhere as default behavior in the framework.

[image]